# How do I mutate column based on value returned from custom function?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to write a function that can return the artist's genre on Spotify based on their Spotify ID. This is with the `spotifyr` package. Consider the following dataframe `artists`:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  id                     name           
  <chr>                  <chr>          
1 6ltzsmQQbmdoHHbLZ4ZN25 Lord Huron     
2 35U9lQaRWSQISxQAB94Meo America        
3 22WZ7M8sxp5THdruNY3gXt The Doors      
4 2MSlGNpwXDScUdspOK6TS7 Home Free      
5 4GITZM5LCR2KcdlgEOrNLD The Foundations
6 2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5 The Zombies
```

My function, `get_genre` is defined as follows:

```
get_genre <- function(x) {
    artist <- get_artist(x)
    artist <- enframe(artist)
    genre <- artist[3,2]
    genre <- as.data.frame(genre)
    return(genre)
}
```

For example, for the id `6ltzsmQQbmdoHHbLZ4ZN25` , it returns:

```
c("indie folk", "indie pop", "stomp and holler")
```

I would like to use it on each row of the `artists` dataframe, for each artist id. I tried doing this:

```
artists <- artists %>% mutate(genre = get_genre(id))
```

But this gives the following error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `genre`. x length(url) == 1 is not TRUE i Input `genre` is `get_genre(id)`.
```

How can I mutate a new column `genre` whose values are returned by my function for each artist id?

DPUT:

```
structure(list(id = c("6ltzsmQQbmdoHHbLZ4ZN25", "35U9lQaRWSQISxQAB94Meo", 
"22WZ7M8sxp5THdruNY3gXt", "2MSlGNpwXDScUdspOK6TS7", "4GITZM5LCR2KcdlgEOrNLD", 
"2jgPkn6LuUazBoBk6vvjh5"), name = c("Lord Huron", "America", 
"The Doors", "Home Free", "The Foundations", "The Zombies")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not vectorized, use `rowwise`. Also since one `id` can return more than 1 genre you can use `toString` to combine everything in one comma separated string.

```
library(dplyr)

artists <- artists %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(genre = toString(get_genre(id)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to read up rowwise and vectorized functions, I think I'm still unclear on the distinction.

Comment: Vectorized functions are faster than rowwise, because the first one apply a function in every element of a vector or column "at the same time". rowwise apply the function at one row at a time. Btw, @Ronak Shah, please, can you provide a vectorized version of this?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
artists <- artists %>%
              mutate(genre = map_chr(id, ~ toString(get_genre(.x))))
```